# How to reduce the screen size with touch?

Tags: html, angular, responsive, viewport

I am developing an app with Angular and would like to be able to shrink my screen on mobile devices even with touch. Zooming in is possible via the viewport, but zooming out does not work.

My viewport looks like this:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

What do I have to do to reach my goal? Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you can remove or change this property to `"user-scalable=yes"`. or you can write it like this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

This will allow users to zoom out and shrink the screen on mobile devices.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in Opera